# After groupby and apply function, output column names missing

Tags: python, group-by, apply

I was applying functions by subgroups to a data frame

```
output = mydf.groupby(['a','b','c']).apply(function)
```

In the output display, columns a,b and c column names are at a lower level compared to model output values, and when i list output, the column a,b,c are not shown in result.

```
list(output.columns)
```

I tried to set as_index = False at dataframe when apply the function but still doesn't work. What i'm missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

reset_index() worked.

```
output = mydf.groupby(['a','b','c']).apply(function).reset_index()
```

solved my problem